# iOS - Embedded Service SDK - Authorization

Tags: ios, embedded-services

I'm trying to implement Case Management as an Authenticated User, I've been following the iOS documentation around this, but I'm a bit confused in some topics, I have some questions which I would really appreciate some help :)

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.service_sdk_ios.meta/service_sdk_ios/case_mgmt_authenticated_user.htm#authentication

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.service_sdk_ios.meta/service_sdk_ios/ios_authentication.htm#ios_authentication

Looking at both diagrams that are in the last URL, I'm not understanding what does the entity *Authorization Server* represents...

Q1: Do I need to set up an Auth provider in Salesforce side ?

Q2: I tried to set up an Auth provider in Salesforce side, but it gives me some URLs.. is the data that we need to have to initialise `SCSAuthenticationSettings` provided by any of this URLs ?
[image]

I assume one of those URLs would be the one that I replace here in the `https://example.com/auth`, but every url doesn't seem to return the access_token or any clientID...

```
  /**
   Implementation of a `ServiceCloudDelegate` method that allows you to
   authenticate for a given service.
   */
  func serviceCloud(_ serviceCloud: ServiceCloud,
                    shouldAuthenticateServiceType service: SCServiceType,
                    completion: @escaping (SCSAuthenticationSettings?) -> Void) -> Bool {
 
    // Rather than scrutinize the service to see if we want to authenticate,
    // let's just assume that we always want to authenticate...
    
    // TO DO: Authenticate asynchronously
    let urlRequest = URLRequest.init(url: URL(string: "https://example.com/auth")!)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
 
      // TO DO: Populate the `SCSAuthenticationSettings` object from the result.
      var authSettings: SCSAuthenticationSettings?
 
      // Call the completion block with the authentication settings (asynchronously)
      completion(authSettings)
      
    }.resume()
    
    // Tell the SDK that we do plan to authenticate
    return true
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Authorization Server is Salesforce. It's also a Resource Server. In terms of oAuth protocol, these two entities have prescribed behavior and each entity could be a physically separate service. In your use case they happen to be under one roof.

Auth provider is needed when you're trying to sign in to Salesforce with a user account from another identity service such as Facebook or Google. It doesn't appear to be your use case so you don't need it.

Embedded Service SDK assumes that your mobile app will be authorized (possess an access token) *prior* to calling methods in SDK. The documentation doesn't make it extremely clear but they do [mention](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.service_sdk_ios.meta/service_sdk_ios/ios_authentication.htm) it. The authorization steps in whatever framework you're using to develop your mobile app depend on that framework. If you're rolling with Salesforce's Mobile SDK as the aforementioned framework, take a look at the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/intro_oauth.htm).